# Similarity finder , optimizations

Tags: pandas, numpy, set, nested-loops, similarity

```
root_words = [set(f'word{i}')for i in range(10000)]
num_root_words = len(root_words)

def findsim(root_words):
    
    pair_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, word_i in enumerate(root_words):
        for j in range(i + 1, num_root_words):
            word_j = root_words[j]
            if len(word_i & word_j) > 3:
                pair_dict[i].append(j)
    return pair_dict
```

pairdict =findsim(root_words) Any way to make this function run faster?

I tried using NumPy related optimization's but was still slow, need to improve the time of execution

Answer (score 0):

This should help to get you started: You can assign each distinct value to a bit and then use bitwise `&`, which is a lot faster than using set comparison. You can then vectorize comparing each element, and produce lists of indexes with >3 elements in common without a python loop.

You might want to use a different value than `3` to check your results - all the items have `word` in common.

```
import collections
import timeit
import numpy as np
root_words = [set(f'word{i}') for i in range(10000)]


def orig():
    num_root_words = len(root_words)
    def findsim(root_words):
        pair_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for i, word_i in enumerate(root_words):
            for j in range(i + 1, num_root_words):
                word_j = root_words[j]
                if len(word_i & word_j) > 3:
                    pair_dict[i].append(j)
        return pair_dict
    return findsim(root_words)


def bit_np():
    def enough_common_elems(spot, item, rest, gt_common_elems=3):
        common = item & rest
        common_elems = ((common >> 0 & 1) +
                        (common >> 1 & 1) +
                        (common >> 2 & 1) +
                        (common >> 3 & 1) +
                        (common >> 4 & 1) +
                        (common >> 5 & 1) +
                        (common >> 6 & 1) +
                        (common >> 7 & 1)).sum(axis=1)
        return (np.where(common_elems > gt_common_elems)[0] + spot + 1).tolist()

    def findsim(root_words_sets):
        valid_chrs = list(set.union(*root_words_sets))
        bit_reprs = np.array([sum([2 ** bit for bit in range(len(valid_chrs)) if valid_chrs[bit] in word]) for word in
                              root_words_sets]).transpose()
        n_bytes = (len(valid_chrs) + 7) // 8
        bit_np_vals = np.zeros((len(root_words_sets), n_bytes), dtype='u1')

        for byte in range(n_bytes):
            bit_np_vals[:, byte] = bit_reprs >> 8 * byte & 255
        ret = {}
        for i, word_i in enumerate(bit_np_vals):
            common_elems = enough_common_elems(i, word_i, bit_np_vals[i+1:, :])
            if common_elems:
                ret[i] = common_elems
        return ret
    return findsim(root_words)


bef = timeit.timeit('orig()', number=3, globals=globals())
aft = timeit.timeit('bit_np()', number=3, globals=globals())
print(bef, aft, bef/aft)
assert orig() == bit_np()
```

On my PC, I see a 4.5x speedup:

```
34.5807251 7.576571700000002 4.564165227922279
```